# Automate disabling of Azure Web App Backup

Tags: azure-web-apps, azure-powershell

I have about 1000 azure web apps that I've recently enabled backup for via `Edit-AzureRmWebAppBackupConfiguration`.

I've taken the backups and now I wish to disable the backups (analogous to the reset button pictured here)

[image: reset button]

I'm struggling to find a way to automate this task for all of the apps. How can this be done?

I'm comfortable using either powershell, CLI, or HTTP, but I just can't find any documented way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/deletebackupconfiguration

I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Interesting, did this work out for you?  Have similar challenges.